# Understanding the execution of command *__SIMD32(pIn)++ in embedded C

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, firmware, cmsis

```
    int8_t scratchbuffer[27000];

    *pV = scratchbuffer;
    *pSRC=pV;
    *pIn=pSRC;
```

I need to understand solving of *__SIMD32(pIn)++

The definitions are mentioned below.

```
    #define __SIMD32_TYPE int32_t
    #define __SIMD32(addr)        (*(__SIMD32_TYPE **) & (addr))
```

Step by step, how do we reach to the output, and what would be the output ?

I tried searching internet for explanations, but couldn't find any.

Answer (score 2):

It's just some preprocessor magic,  `*__SIMD32(pIn)++`, with the definitions you show after the preprocessor becomes `*(*(int32_t **) & (pIn))++`. This gives you a 32 bit read of `pIn`, and then increments `pIn` by 32 bits. See [here](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=9YxqAAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA685&ots=Ub84ObfEhG&dq=__SIMD32%20cmsis&pg=PA685#v=onepage&q&f=false) for more detail.